# A better way to convert a directory of files into bytes

Tags: java, file

I have been messing with this for some time and it's getting better and better, but it's still a little slow for me. Can anyone help speed this up / make the design better, please?

Also, the files must only be numbers and the file must end with the file extension ".dat"
I never added the checks because I didn't feel is was necessary.

```
public void preloadModels() {
    try {
        File directory = new File(signlink.findcachedir() + "raw", File.separator);
        File[] modelFiles = directory.listFiles();
        for (int modelIndex = modelFiles.length - 1;; modelIndex--) {
            String modelFileName = modelFiles[modelIndex].getName();
            byte[] buffer = getBytesFromInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(directory, modelFileName)));
            Model.method460(buffer, Integer.parseInt(modelFileName.replace(".dat", "")));
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        return;
    }
}

public static final byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
    int bufferSize = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int read = inputStream.read(buffer, bufferSize, buffer.length - bufferSize);
        if (read == -1) {
            return Arrays.copyOf(buffer, bufferSize);
        }
        bufferSize += read;
        if (bufferSize == buffer.length) {
            buffer = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, bufferSize * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like something more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what is the difference may I ask? And is this not an appropriate question?

Comment: This site is for asking questions about something that doesn't work in some programming aspect. For improvements to code, you go to codereview.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Bookmarked that site for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following.

```
public void preloadModels() throws IOException {
    File directory = new File(signlink.findcachedir() + "raw");
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (!file.getName().endsWith(".dat")) continue;
        byte[] buffer = getBytesFromFile(file);
        Model.method460(buffer, Integer.parseInt(file.getName().replace(".dat", "")));
    }
}

public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
        dis.readFully(buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

If this is still too slow, most likely the limitation is the speed of hard drive.

Comment: Ohh. That makes much more sense than what I was doing.
And what about the first bit?

Comment: That was the original code I was messing with, I didn't add that part myself. But yeah. I was thinking, could I iterate through the directory like for (File file : new File(...).listFiles())
                      ...
?

Comment: Never mind! I see you edited your post before I finished my comment.
Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

How about using Apache Commons IOUtils class.

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)
```

Comment: I know of it, but I don't want to have an external library. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add all directories content to archive. Have a look at [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html). It has some bugs with file names before 7th version. There is also Apache Commons implementation.